# not showing results in append of node in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

i have written a code to append nodes if empty or not.
I think my code and logic is correct but still i am not able to get any answer . its compiling but after running not showing any result . please tell me why

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *nxt;
};

void append(struct node *,int);
void display(struct node*);

void append( struct node *q, int num )
{
    struct node *temp,*r;
    if(q == NULL)
    {
        temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp -> data = num;
        temp -> nxt = NULL;
        q = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = q;
        while(temp->nxt != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->nxt;
        }
        r = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        r -> data = num;
        r -> nxt = NULL;
        temp->nxt = r;
    }
}

void display(struct node *q)
{
    while(q != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",q->data);
        q = q->nxt;
    }
}


int main()
{
    struct node *a;
    a= NULL;
    append(a,10);
    append(a,11);
    append(a,12);
    display(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the address of the first parameter (the list head) to the `append` method by address. As written, it is passing NULL in the first call (and each subsequent call) because it is passing by value.

The prototype should look something like this:

```
void append( struct node **q, int num )
```

And then make calls like this:

```
append(&a,10);
```

Note that the function `append` needs to be updated accordingly to treat the parameter change correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The prototype of append needs to be changed as

```
void append( struct node **q, int num );
```

and pass the address of the `a` as `&a` to this function. This is because C only supports pass by value. Learn more on this [here](http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/catam/ccatsl/manual/node50.html).

Please find the modified append function as below:

```
void append( struct node **q, int num ) 
{     
  struct node *temp,*r;     

  if(*q == NULL)     
  {         
     temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     temp -> data = num;
     temp -> nxt = NULL;
     *q = temp;
  }
  else
  {
     temp = *q;
     while(temp->nxt != NULL)
     {
         temp = temp->nxt;
     }
     r = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     r -> data = num;
     r -> nxt = NULL;
     temp->nxt = r;
 } 
}
```

In addition:

Chane the below line:

```
printf("%d",q->data);
```

as

```
printf("%d\n",q->data);
```

printf might not flush data unless there is a newline in some terminals.

Comment: In most systems that I have dealt with, the new line is not necessary to flush the data.  However, you are correct that the OP likely does want the newline (or at least a space between the values with a newline at the end of the function).

Comment: @Mark Wilkins, As you say, OP needs a newline for the output to appear clear to the viewer. But, also I have faced this problem long back when I was new to programming, though I don't remember the terminal now. Also, for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Comment: The if / else is not needed once you have the double pointer to seek to the end. `void append( struct node **q, int num )
{

  for(; *q ; q = &(*q)->nxt) {;}

  *q = malloc(sizeof **q );
  (*q)->data = num;
  (*q)->nxt = NULL;
} 
`

Comment: @Mark Wilkins, Anyways, I edit my answer to reflect that it might not print in some terminals if newline is not present. I guess using "will not" makes it more of a sure behavior. Thanks for your comment. : )

Comment: @wildplasser, Got it. : ) I usually write it in the same manner as OP, as I find such kind of code more readable.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers , i got where i was wrong , thank you:)